# Inheritance and Polymorphism in LINQ Lambdas

Tags: .net, linq, inheritance, lambda, .net-4.5

I've got a couple of classes inheriting from a base class

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Public Property Name as String
End Class

Public MustInherit Class ClassA
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Property Something As String
End Class

Public MustInherit Class ClassB
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Property SomethingElse As String
End Class
```

I want to be able to use a single expression to query multiple lists of objects, all of which inherit from the same base class

```
Public Function DoStuff(Expression as System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of BaseClass, Boolean)))
    Dim ListA As New List(Of ClassA) ''Populating this elsewhere
    Dim ListB As New List(Of ClassB) ''and this

    Dim ResultSetA = ListA.Where(Expression) ''Problems on this line
    Dim ResultSetB = ListA.Where(Expression) ''and this
End Function
```

Since both `ClassA` and `ClassB` inherit from the same base class, and since the LINQ query is against the base class, it *should* work. The `Expression` can only refer to properties of the base class which are guaranteed to be present on both derived classes but I get the following compile-time typing error:

```
Value of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of BaseClass, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of ClassA, Boolean))'
```

Is there any way I can add a widening conversion (or something similar) to allow this to work?

or do I need to provide the exact same query multiple times against each derived class?

Comment: I think you need the Linq Cast<BaseClass> before the where, but I don't know the VB syntax. I'm guessing it might be .Cast(Of BaseClass) ?

Comment: Did you mean to pass in a `Func` instead of an `Expression`?

Comment: @HenryP Actually, no. I've simplified the above example as I'm actually running this against entities in a Db, the Lists are repositories and I've got some other things going on in there which dynamically modify the expression tree. The Baseclass in question is a generic `Job` base which all entities representing jobs inherit from

Comment: @podiluska Can you give me a c# example and I'll convert? `List(Of ClassA)` doesn't have a `.Cast()` method - unless you mean Cast the list as a whole before querying? In which case, `ResultSetA` and `ResultSetB` are of type `BaseClass` - and I'd like to be able to access their class-specific properties

Comment: I see. `Expression` does not seem to be contravariant (co? always mix them up). It is possible you could work around it by compiling into a `Func`. Does replacing it with `...Where(Expression.Compile())` work for you?

Comment: @HenryP I always get them the wrong way 'round too. `Compile()`ing just gives the same error

Comment: @HenryP looks like you were 90% right, podiluska's `AsQueryable` turned the trick, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `AsQueryable()` your list (c# syntax below)

```
var ResultA = lista.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
```

You can then cast the results back to the original types if you need to

```
 foreach (var x in ResultA)
 {
      Response.Write(((ClassA)x).Something);
 }
```

Comment: Good catch - Actually, by making it `IQueryable` and using @HenryP's suggestion of compiling the query, I can do it without the cast.... `ListA.AsQueryable.Where(Expression.Compile)`. Thanks!